# Prove that the sequence: $a_1 = 1, a_{n+1} =\sqrt{c+da_n}$ (when the real numbers $c, d > 1$) is converging and find it's limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations, radicals

I have a summarized solution but it's starts with proving that the sequence is bounded from above by c+d.
How can I know that this sequence is bounded by c+d? I understand the proof by induction but how do I actually realize that fact?

I know how to prove that the sequence is monotonically increasing and to find it's limit after we've established that the sequence is converging.

Comment: Do you mean a proof that it is bounded by $c+d$? If $c+d<a_{n+1}=\sqrt{c+d a_n}$ then $c^2+2cd+d^2<c+d a_n$, so $2cd+d^2<d a_n$ (since $c^2>c$), so $2cd<0$ (since $d^2>d a_n$, since $d>1$ and $a_n>1$ because it is increasing), this is absurd.

Comment: I meant bounded from above. thanks.

Comment: My comment is not correct, the last step is not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** If you already managed to prove that the sequence is increasing, you have that the sequence is either divergent to $+\infty$ or converging to some limit $l>0$. In the second case, such a number must fulfill $l=\sqrt{c+dl}$, hence:
$$ l=\frac{d+\sqrt{4c+d^2}}{2}. $$
On the other hand, $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is bounded:
$$ a_{n+1}^2 \leq (c+d)\,a_n\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \left(\frac{a_{n+1}^2}{a_n}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{a_{n}^2}{a_{n-1}}\right)^{1/2}\cdot\ldots\cdot\left(\frac{a_{2}^2}{a_1}\right)^{2/2^n}\leq (c+d)^2$$
from which it follows that $a_n\leq(c+d)$ for any $n\geq 1$.

Comment: I still don't get it.
I understand that the sequence is either divergent to infinity or converging to some limit. I understand that in the second case the limit equals to $\sqrt{c+dl}$. How do I prove that the sequence is bound by c+d?
forget about formal proof for a second, how do I even know that? It looks like a wild guess to me at this point.

Comment: @Agami: The upper bound is just a consequence of $a_{n+1}^2 \leq \color{red}{(c+d)}\cdot a_n$.

Comment: But isn't $a^2_{n+1} = c+da_n$ ?

Comment: @Agami: yes, in particolar $a_{n+1}\leq (c+d) a_n$.

Comment: Why do you go from $a_{n+1}^2 = c+da_n$ to $a^2_{n+1}\leq (c+d)a_n$ ?

Comment: Through $a_n\geq 1$, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an upper bound $M$ for the sequence $a_n$, then you're going to want:

- $a_1=1\le M$
- $a_n\le M\implies a_{n+1}\le M$

  - Now, if all we know about $a_n$ is that it's $\le M$, then the best bound we can have for $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{c+da_n}\le\sqrt{c+dM}$. For this to guarantee $a_{n+1}\le M$, we need $\sqrt{c+dM}\le M$, i.e. $M^2-dM-c\ge0$. If we call the negative root of this equation $-s$, and the positive root $r$, this becomes $(M+s)(M-r)\ge0$, which leads to $M\ge r$ (excluding the case of negative bounds because we know $a_n\ge1>0$). So, the tightest upper bound we can establish for $a_n$ is $r$ (which we probably suspect to be its limit).

To confirm that our sequence is monotonically increasing, we note that for $a_n \ge 0$, $a_{n+1}\ge a_n\iff a_{n+1}^2\ge a_n^2\iff c+da_n\ge a_n^2$

$$\iff a_n^2-da_n-c\le0\iff (a_n+s)(a_n-r)\le0$$

Now, we know that $0\le a_n \le r$, so this sequence is increasing for all $n$ and bounded above by $r$, hence convergent.

Finally, denoting the limit of $a_n$ by $L$, we see that $a_{n+1}$ will have the same limit, and standard observations tell us that $L=\sqrt{c+dL}$, which has solutions $L=-s,r$. Noting that $a_n\ge0$ for all $n$ gives that the limit must be $r$, and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

We can apply $a_n \le d+2c+\frac{c^2-c}{d}$ also to show that $a_n$ is bounded, instead to show $a_n \le d+c$. The point is that we can still apply monotone convergence theorem.

For $n=1$, $a_1=1 < d+2c+\frac{c^2-c}{d}$. Then suppose that $a_n < d+2c+\frac{c^2-c}{d}$ for some $n$. Then
\begin{align}
a_{n+1}&=\sqrt{c+da_n}\\
&\le\sqrt{c+d\left(d+2c+\frac{c^2-c}{d}\right)}\\
&=\sqrt{c^2+2cd+d^2}\\
&=c+d\\
&\le c+d+\left(c+\frac{c^2-c}{d}\right)\\
&=d+2c+\frac{c^2-c}{d}.
\end{align}
By mathematical induction, the inequality holds for all positive integer $n$.

Comment: How did you get to the expression $d+2c+\frac{c^2-c}{d}$ in the first place?

Comment: I constructed $d+2c+\frac{c^2-c}{d}$ by setting $\sqrt{c+dx}=c+d$ to make $\sqrt{c+da_n}$ be a perfect square and remove root symbol easily. Fortunately it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Better idea: the equation $a = \sqrt{c+da}$ has a solution
$$a = a_0 := \frac{d+\sqrt{4c+d^2}}2>d>1$$
and for $a\in[1,a_0]$: $a\le\sqrt{c+da}\le a_0$, i.e.,
$$a_n\le a_{n+1}\le a_0$$

Answer (score 0):

If a sequence is increasing and bounded, then it converges to the supremum of the values. If it is increasing and unbounded, then it diverges to $\infty$.

So all you need is to prove the sequence is increasing and bounded.

Let's try seeing $a_1\le a_2,$ which means $1\le\sqrt{c+d}$, which is true because $1\le c+d$.

Now, suppose you know that $a_n\le a_{n+1}$; then the inequality
$$
a_{n+1}\le a_{n+2}
$$
is equivalent to
$$
c+da_n\le c+da_{n+1}
$$
which clearly follows from the induction hypothesis.

We just have to guess a bound. But we *know* what to look for: the sequence is increasing, so the limit must be an upper bound.

So, suppose the sequence is convergent to $a$; then
$$
a=\sqrt{c+da}
$$
so
$$
a^2=c+da
$$
and
$$
a^2-da-c=0
$$
so
$$
a=\frac{d+\sqrt{d^2+4c}}{2}
$$
must be the limit *and* an upper bound for the sequence.

Note that $a>1$, so the base of the induction is established. Suppose that $a_n\le a$; then $a_{n+1}\le a$ is equivalent to
$$
c+da_n\le \left(\frac{d+\sqrt{d^2+4c}}{2}\right)^2
$$
which becomes
$$
4c+4da_n\le d^2+d^2+4c+2d\sqrt{d^2+4c}
$$
that is, after simplifying,
$$
2a_n\le d+\sqrt{d^2+4c}
$$
which is precisely the induction hypothesis.

---

If you want to show the sequence is bounded by $c+d$, you can do this way. First, $a_1\le c+d$ is true. Suppose $a_n\le c+d$; then $a_{n+1}\le c+d$ is equivalent to
$$
c+da_n\le (c+d)^2
$$
that is,
$$
a_n\le\frac{(c+d)^2-c}{d}
$$
and you'll be done if you prove that
$$
\frac{(c+d)^2-c}{d}\ge c+d
$$
which becomes
$$
(c+d)^2-cd-d^2-c\ge0
$$
or
$$
c^2+d(c-1)\ge0
$$
which is true.

Answer (score 0):

If the sequence defined recursively by
$a_{n+1}:=\sqrt{c+da_n}$ converges then the limit $\alpha>0$ satisfies the equation
$$\alpha^2=c+d\alpha\ ,$$
hence
$$\alpha={1\over2}\bigl(d+\sqrt{d^2+4c}\bigr)>d\ .$$
Therefore let's look at the quantities $x_n:=a_n-\alpha$. From the given recurrence we get
$$x_{n+1}=a_{n+1}-\alpha={\bigl(c+ d( x_n+\alpha)\bigr)-\alpha^2\over\sqrt{c+da_n}+\alpha}={d\over\sqrt{c+da_n}+\alpha}\>x_n\qquad(n\geq0)\ .$$
Since
$$0<{d\over\sqrt{c+da_n}+\alpha}<{d\over 1+d}<1$$
it follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=0$, hence $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=\alpha$ whenever $a_0\geq0$.